# CORS Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present but OPTIONS and POST request get 200 but

Tags: javascript, php, api

I cannot get a CORS request to work and this is day 4 battling with it. I am getting a 200 on my OPTIONS request and also a 200 on my POST request and all of the headers look like it should work, but I am still getting the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`.

I am using Laravel (PHP) and the Fetch API in a React app.

Here is a screenshot of my OPTIONS request and the following POST request:

OPTIONS request

[image: OPTIONS request]

POST request
[image]

Comment: `but I am still getting the error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present.` - well ... you aren't getting that in the `POST` **response** headers, are you - you've put it in the request header, which doesn't actually mean anything

Comment: I thought that header was only on the initial `OPTIONS` request? So, are you saying I need to add that to the request?

Comment: on the server, in the **response** to the request, yes - you've already put it in the request (which means nothing)

Comment: @dericcain, Not the request, put it on the _response_.

Comment: I have a package taking care of that for me so I'll need to look real quick and see what is going on.

Comment: remove `access-control-allow-origin` from the request while you're at it - doesn't cause any problems, except it could trigger an otherwise unrequired preflight - in this particular case, the preflight will take place regardless, due to the value of the requested `content-type`

Comment: *I have a package taking care of that for me* - really? not a great package, since it responds to options that `access-control-allow-origin` is an allowed request header - and doesn't add any CORS headers to the POST response

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to and it's been frustrating the crap out of me.

Answer (score 0):

What it ended up being was I had `dd(variable)` which is a dump and die, in my controller. For some reason, this was causing the CORS error, which can be explained better here: [look for this comment: davidnknight commented on Sep 26, 2014](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/15)

To paraphrase: If your backend is throwing errors or not completing successfully, you will get CORS errors because the correct headers are not being sent.

So, make sure your backend is working properly.